# Angular $resource get single record. Response but no data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

As my title says I am having an issue where I can not get data to return correctly using the $resource get method. In my chrome browser I just see [object Object] for the data but the response is showing the "success" string correctly. So I am returning the data I just cannot use it! If I change it to a query with no params and call a different web api method that returns a list it works fine. It is just when I am trying to get a single record. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: AngularJS v1.3.0-rc.5
Edit2: Looks like in the console it is showing it as an array
        Resource {0: "S", 1: "u", 2: "c", 3: "c", 4: "e", 5: "s", 6: "s", $promise: Promise, 
$resolved: true, toJSON: function, $get: function, $save: function…}

```
app.controller('fooController', function ($scope, fooService) {
    $scope.person = function (person) {
        fooService.get({ firstName: person.firstName, lastName: person.lastName })
            .$promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.person.exist = data;
            });
     }
});

app.factory('fooService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://****.com/api/values/:lastName/:firstName', {
        get: { method: 'GET', isArray: false}
    });
});

//web api get 
public string Get(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    return "Success";
}
```

Comment: how would you expect angular to handle the fact that you returned a string?  you should return an object

Comment: The default scaffolding in web api for a get with parameter returns just a string.

Comment: Ahhh. I get it. I guess I just assumed the default scaffolding in visual studio was correct for rest. I changed my Get method to return the first item in a list and it worked perfect. Thanks for your help!